# Drawer Navigation position right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

Drawer Navigation position right gives odd behavior.
[Here's the behavior of drawer when position is set to right](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YDiuUd_b1G7axG83fdgX1qWs-V_ADddJ/view?usp=sharing)

I am not sure why is it giving this behavior, because it should be working like it works in default for left.
Here is my code

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{drawerPosition: 'right'}}>
     <Drawer.Screen name="Test" component={Test} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Enviroment

```
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^5.1.0",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.2",
"react-native-bootsplash": "^4.1.3",
"react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.3.0",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.11.1",
"react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0"
```

Kindly help me out in it.
Thankyou

Comment: You should add a minimal working example of your situation using something like codesandbox.io

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
screenOptions={{drawerPosition:'right',headerShown:false,drawerStyle:{right:0}}}
```